# How to tell if Fisher information is well defined?

Tags: fisher-information

I'm asked to determine whether the Fisher information is well defined for a number of distributions. I think I understand how to actually compute the fisher information, at least for the standard distributions, but I'm not sure exactly what "well defined" means or how to test for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only means that it is a well-defined function:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined

There are cases where the Fisher information does not exist (or is $\infty$) at some points.

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. You could 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.